# Is raw coconut safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety, coconut, salmonella

I recently came across this study:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC546945/?page=1

and I am worried about potential salmonella infection in raw coconut meat and whole coconut picked up from my local grocery store (i.e. thai grocery, local organic shop). Is it necessary to pasteurise the meat before consumption? If yes, would the pieces of coconut meat they sell be pasteurised?

Would it be safer to purchase pre-cut coconut meat, or a whole coconut?

Answer (score 4):

IMO, stated again, IMO...

It is an old research paper (1967) about mostly transformed (grated and dried) coconut.

A quick googling does not really give more warnings for whole coconuts (FDA or other sources).

Like all things "exotic", wash the exterior under clean water before opening and use properly clean knives and other kitchen tools.

Enjoy the coconut.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is :) When I was a kid , we used to have fresh tender coconut from our tress and after  drinking the water , we used to cut open the coconut and have the coconut. Like wise its even the same with the coconut in store. But  since they are packaged and handle my many, just rinse it before eating .